# Select first three rows for each ID

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have executed the following query:

```
SELECT ProductID, Quantity, Location 
FROM DBLocations
ORDER BY ProductID, LocationDistanceIndex DESC;
```

Afterwards, I've been trying to select up to 3 closest warehouses which have each of the products - `LocationDistanceIndex` column (Also there could be none, 1 or 2).

How would I write the query to remain with up to 3 records for each ProductID - the 3 records with the highest LocationDistanceIndex hence the descending order by.

Also if there is a way to perform such filtering without manually written queries in MS Access, it would be great if somebody points that out.
Note: I tried using Row_Number() Over Partition but MS Access does not seem to support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method for MS Access:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM DBLocations l
WHERE l.LocationDistanceIndex IN (SELECT TOP 3 l2.LocationDistanceIndex
                                  FROM DBLocations l2
                                  WHERE l.ProductID = l2.ProductID
                                  ORDER BY l2.LocationDistanceIndex DESC
                                 );
```

Comment: Might need to fix the alias on the subquery. It currently says `from DBLocations l`, but I think your intention was `from DB Locations l2`.

Comment: Thank you, You made it look easy!